# How to calculate panel bootsrapped standard errors with R?

Tags: r

I recently changed from STATA to R and somehow struggles to find some corresponding commands. I would like to get panel bootsrapped standard errors from a Fixed Effect model using the `plm` library as described here [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/bootstrap-with-panel-data/) for STATA users:

1. My questions concern the approach in general (whether boot is the appropriate library or the library(meboot)
   )
2. How to solve for that particular error using boot:

First get some panel data:

```
library(plm)
data(EmplUK) # from plm library

test<-function(data, i) coef(plm(wage~emp+sector,data = data[i,],
                                      index=c("firm","year"),model="within"))
```

Second:

```
library(boot)
boot<-boot(EmplUK, test, R = 100)

> boot<-boot(EmplUK, test, R = 100)
  duplicate couples (time-id)
  Error in pdim.default(index[[1]], index[[2]]) : 
  Called from: top level 
  Browse[1]>
```

Comment: Why don't you show the error message?

Comment: thx all for the interest @ agstudy using that appoach somehow leads to std. error=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason , `boot` will pass an index ( original here) to `plm` with duplicated values. You should remove all duplicated values and assert that the index is **unique** before passing it to `plm`.

```
test <- function(data,original) {
   coef(plm(wage~emp+sector,data = data[unique(original),],
       index=c("firm","year"),model="within"))
}


boot(EmplUK, test, R = 100)

## ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
## Call:
## boot(data = EmplUK, statistic = test, R = 100)
## Bootstrap Statistics :
##       original      bias    std. error
## t1* -0.1198127 -0.01255009  0.05269375
```

Comment: @Mamba You are welcome. Maybe you should contact the package maintainer to add this assertion in the code. It looks like a bug or at least this feature is not documented.

Comment: By removing duplicate values, does this not mean that each repetition could have a differnet size of resample (and is also now not sample with replacement)? Apologies if im missing the obvious!

Comment: Does mean sampling without repetition , but samples should not all have the same size.

Comment: So for one resample, if there are many duplicated rows, by then making these unique you get a much reduced dataset to generate coeffiecients, then another repetition, if there are few duplicated rows, the coefficients are estimated on a larger dataset. Will this not affect the nice properties of non-parametric bootstrap? (idk)

Comment: Note that bootstrapping uses sampling with replacement. If you do not allow duplicates, it is not the boostrap method anymore and you need to prove that the derived statistics are good estimators of the population's statistics.

Comment: @user20650 personally I don't know. I just fix the bug from programming point of view. I think you should ask the maintainer of the package for more statistical details.

Comment: @agstudy No, this doesn't concern the maintainers of the boot nor plm packages. Personally, I might try bootstrapping the residuals. But I've never used plm models.

Comment: @ Roland which package for panel data analysis as well as for panel bootsrapped standard errors do you recommend?